# ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded while using WGET to filter a simple api request from CLI in linux

Tags: python, api, command-line-interface, wget

Basically I cant use curl in a simple linux machine but i have WGET. 
I have this json

```
{
 "inStandby": "false", 
 "currservice_begin": "10:38", 
 "currservice_begin_timestamp": 34332, 
 "currservice_end_timestamp": 15759723423500, 
 "muted": false, 
 "isRecording": "false", 
 "currservice_station": "02 2 HD", 
 "currservice_serviceref": "1:0:19:4B0:1:1:334:0:0:0:", 
 "currservice_description": "Mv i v", 
 "volume": 50, 
 "currservice_fulldescription": "asdfasd", 
 "currservice_filename": "", 
 "transcoding": true, 
 "currservice_end": "11:25", 
 "currservice_id": 36172
}
```

I am trying to print only the "currservice_serviceref" value to a file. I tried

```
wget localhost/api/statusinfo | python -c 'import json,sys;data=json.load(sys.stdin);print data["currservice_serviceref"]'
```

Comment: ...and what happened when you tried that? Also, is this the complete JSON or are there `[]` around it by any chance?

Comment: Also, there is no `currentservice` key in your JSON.

Comment: @Tomalak I wrote the error i get in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by adding -qO- (which prints to stdout) because i think python was trying to read from stdin (sys.stdin ).